# Spring .jar is not starting

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

When I run my project in IntelliJ it works fine, server starts etc. but when I build my project (with maven) and I want to execute the .jar file I get those errors:

```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class:
> at.ennui.backend.facebook.configuration.SocialConfig
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:403)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:249)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
> ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at at.ennui.backend.EnnuiApplication.main(EnnuiApplication.java:12)
> [classes!/:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE] Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:480)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:337)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:138)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:110)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:393)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         ... 20 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/social/facebook/connect/FacebookConnectionFactory
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:566)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.transform.TransformingClassGenerator.generateClass(TransformingClassGenerator.java:33)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanFactoryAwareGeneratorStrategy.generate(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:252)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generate(Enhancer.java:492)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         ... 28 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:94)
> ~[EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         ... 42 common frames omitted
> 
> 2017-09-27 15:10:03.076  INFO 6740 --- [           main]
> ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing
> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5afa04c:
> startup date [Wed Sep 27 15:10:01 CEST 2017]; parent:
> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@20fa23c1
> 2017-09-27 15:10:03.076  WARN 6740 --- [           main]
> ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from
> LifecycleProcessor on context close
> 
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized -
> call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context:
> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5afa04c:
> startup date [Wed Sep 27 15:10:01 CEST 2017]; parent:
> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@20fa23c1
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:427)
> [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:999)
> [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
> [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at at.ennui.backend.EnnuiApplication.main(EnnuiApplication.java:12)
> [classes!/:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
> 
> 2017-09-27 15:10:03.091 ERROR 6740 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with
> name
> 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
> threw an exception
> 
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not
> initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the
> context:
> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5afa04c:
> startup date [Wed Sep 27 15:10:01 CEST 2017]; parent:
> org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@20fa23c1
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:414)
> [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
> ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
> ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
> [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
> [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
> [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
> [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.destroySingletons(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:230)
> [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
> [spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
> [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006)
> [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958)
> [spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.10.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:750)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
> [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.6.RELEASE]
>         at at.ennui.backend.EnnuiApplication.main(EnnuiApplication.java:12)
> [classes!/:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
> [EnnuiBackend-1.0.0-RELEASE.jar:1.0.0-RELEASE]
```

The first exception could be because in my SocialConfig  class I use "Environment" to get a property out of the application.properties and no properties are outside of the .jar (Also get it when they are beside the jar) 
But I dont know what the other exceptions are meaning...

Application.class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EnnuiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EnnuiApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper(){
        return new ModelMapper();
    }
}
```

SocialConfig.class:

```
   @Configuration
public class SocialConfig implements SocialConfigurer {

    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
                env.getProperty("facebook.appId"),
                env.getProperty("facebook.appSecret")));
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public UsersConnectionRepository getUsersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>at.ennui</groupId>
    <artifactId>EnnuiBackend</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-RELEASE</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>EnnuiBackend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Miestone Repo</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.M3</version>
        </dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring social facebook dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.M3</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/spring-social-facebook-3.0.0.M3.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.pr3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.M4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--                           -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: The exception says: *ClassNotFoundException:
org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory*. This class is in the spring-social-facebook artifcat, but you've commented out the dependency to replace it with a system dependency pointing at a jar file inside your src/main/resources folder. Don't do that.

Comment: Yeah, but I had to do some changes in the social-facebook library, is there a way to "merge the socia-facebook jar into my project.jar" ?

Comment: Pick a different group/artifact/version for this modified jar, and install it in you company's maven repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JB Nizet pointed out, the problem is with the FacebookConnectionFactory not being supplied.

Directory JARs can be added into the packaging. However, you should consider installing the dependency into local Maven repository and supplying it to the project from there instead of passing it in a directory.

http://roufid.com/3-ways-to-add-local-jar-to-maven-project/